# On the derivative of the Hamiltonian of a particle in quantum mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

The Hamiltonian function for a particle of mass $m$ moving along the $x$-axis, subject to a potential energy $V(x)$, the Hamiltonian function is:

$$H = \frac{p_x ^2}{2m} + V(x).$$

My book states that
$$\frac{\partial{H}}{dx} =  \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial x}.$$

The reason being that the momentum term does not explicitly depend on $x$. However, I don't get why this is the case. Shouldn't the derivative of the Hamiltonian include the derivative of the momentum as the momentum of a particle could depend on its position?

Answer (score 1):

Momenta and positions are independent variables in classical [Hamiltonian formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics).